# Dynamically Create OnClick Event Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a button that has an onclick event programmically..

```
 var removeFunction = "removeEmployee(" + "'" + phone + "'" + "," + "'" + pin + "'" + "," + "'" + employees[i].ID + "'" + ")";

    var removeButton = "<a onclick='" + removeFunction + "' " + "data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext'></a>";
```

I have this function in the same javascript file as the the dynamically created code above. I think it is breaking because I need to add quotes around the string parameters. The above code is an attempt to that but if I look at the created markup it reads..

```
onclick="removeEmployee("
```

Something is making the rest cut off im not sure what? Also will this run as long as I have a funcition named "removeEmployee" located in my javascript file?

Comment: So much for separating HTML and javascript.

Comment: Inspecting the value of `removeButton` would have been enough to notice the problem, and that's called *debugging*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var removeFunction = "removeEmployee('" + phone + "','" + pin + "','" + employees[i].ID + "')";
```

Also:

```
var removeButton = "<a onclick='" + removeFunction + "' data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext'></a>";
```

Comment: this gives the same problem..<a title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext" onclick="removeEmployee(" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperEls="span" data-icon="delete" jQuery18006260579685328433="19" data-iconpos="notext" 7758134094?,?703384996?,?drCZ80?)?="">

Comment: Are you sure the variables exists?  Those variables need to be declared or it will stop the js processing.

Comment: still same result, I am using IE

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code then as I created a file with this stuff and it works fine.  Think you need to supply more information or a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Not to avoid the question, but why wouldn't you do something like this instead:

```
var bindEvent = function(el, event, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener){
    el.addEventListener(event, handler, false); 
  } else if (el.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
  }
}

var removeButton = document.createElement("a");

removeButton.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
removeButton.setAttribute("data-icon", "delete");
removeButton.setAttribute("data-iconpos", "notext");

bindEvent(removeButton, "click", function(){
    removeEmployee(phone, pin, employees[i]['id']);
});
```

Comment: this code gives me "Object doesnt supoprt property or method" on the addEventListener line

Comment: @NickLaMarca that probably goes along with the compatibility thing I had in there before, try the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

In XML codes, you can use either double-quotes or single-quotes for setting strings. In this matter, you should use single-quote, then you can use double-quotes inside your string.

Like this:

```
onclick='removeEmployee("45681", 1, "test")'
```

Or visa versa:

```
onclick="removeEmployee('45681', 1, 'test')"
```

When you write the code you mentioned, it seems like this to the HTML parser:

```
<element onclick='removeEmployee(' 45681=', 1, ' test=')' />
```

In this situation, your element has 3 attributes with three different names, not just "onclick" attribute and **IT IS WRONG**.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var a=document.createElement('a'),
attrs={data-role:'button',data-icon:'delete',data-iconpos:'notext'};
for(var i in attrs){a.setAttribute(i,attrs[i]}
a.onclick=function(){
    removeEmployee(phone,pin,employees[i].ID);
}
```